# Facebook API (PHP) Post available to nobody but me

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a very strange problem. I developed a little PHP-Script and a Facebook-App which posts to my Pages. The App's permissions are: `publish_actions` and `manage_pages`.

And it works like a charm, with one major hook: These Posts aren't visible to anyone but me. They are showing up on my wall, I can see them on the Page and even in Insights, they're visible. See this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqgYt.png

As you can see it's a public post, and only one person saw it: me. Here's the direct link: https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=793772960651385&id=110373632307818

if you click it you'll get the message: "This page is currently unavailable" ... or something like that.

Has anyone else had such a problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: This is the code that does the job:

```
function page_message($page_id, $data){
    // my persistent access-token
    $user_access_token = '◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎';

    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = '353943021379058';
    $config['secret'] = '◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);

    // get the list of my pages
    $response = $facebook->api("/gonzo187/accounts/", 'GET', array('access_token' => $user_access_token));


    $args = $data;

    $args['access_token']  = '';

    foreach($response["data"] as $page){
        if($page["id"] == $page_id){ 
            echo '<!--';
            var_dump($page);
            echo('-->');
            $args["access_token"] = $page["access_token"];
        }
    }

    if($args["access_token"]){
        $return = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed", "post", $args); // It works!!
    }else{
        $return = false;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

EDIT2: the $data-Array:

```
$data = array(
    'page_id'   => '153090891543315',
    'data'      => array(
        'message'   => "wer watchng u!\n\nrly!",  
        'link'      => "https://www.nsa.gov/", 
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Have you made your app public by disabling development mode in your app settings?

Comment: no i hadn't. it is now online. i left it in dev-mode to prevent listing in the app store. is there another way to prevent this?

Comment: Your app is only published, when you start a submission under `Submit Items for Approval`

Comment: Glad to hear; I would like to post it as answer to your question. Please approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable developer mode in your app settings under `review & status`.

From the facebook [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/)

> Development Mode
>
> When testing your apps, place them into Development Mode. This hides
>   your app entirely from all users who you have not authorized in the
>   App Dashboard to see the app, for the roles described below. Please
>   note that when your app is in Development Mode, you cannot call any
>   API calls on behalf of users who cannot see your app.